# On or in for a website?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Change the default branch on github." is correct?

Isi a technical sentence. Github is a website. Need I use "in" or "on" for a website? I do not care what is more appropriate. I care about what is right and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Change the default branch on github.

is correct.

Github is a hosting service and source code is placed **on** it, not **in** it.

In general, things are

> **on** websites
>   **on** servers
>   **on** disk

but

> **in** file systems.